# File not uploaded to directory using go

Tags: go

Am trying to upload files to a directory using go code below.
[source](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-upload-file)

The Issue am having is that when I run the code, it prints **files successfully uploaded** 
but when I get to the directory, **No file is uploaded there**. Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks

```
package main

 import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
 )

 func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // the FormFile function takes in the POST input id file
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
        return
    }

    defer file.Close()

    out, err := os.Create("/upload")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Unable to create the file for writing. Check your write access privilege")
        return
    }

    defer out.Close()

    // write the content from POST to the file
    _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "File uploaded successfully : ")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, header.Filename)
 }

 func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", uploadHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
 }
```

Comment: And where do you check the file? The name `/upload` is **absolute**, it denotes a file in your **root directory**, its being `upload`; it will not be created in the current directory nor in an `upload` subfolder!

Comment: Okay I understand now. Thanks Sir Icza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I get my files uploaded to server. 
[Source](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-file-upload-tutorial/)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("File Upload Endpoint Hit")

    // Parse our multipart form, 10 << 20 specifies a maximum
    // upload of 10 MB files.
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    // FormFile returns the first file for the given key `myFile`
    // it also returns the FileHeader so we can get the Filename,
    // the Header and the size of the file
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("myFile")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Retrieving the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fmt.Printf("Uploaded File: %+v\n", handler.Filename)
    fmt.Printf("File Size: %+v\n", handler.Size)
    fmt.Printf("MIME Header: %+v\n", handler.Header)

    // Create a temporary file within our temp-images directory that follows
    // a particular naming pattern
    tempFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("temp-images", "upload-*.png")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer tempFile.Close()

    // read all of the contents of our uploaded file into a
    // byte array
    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // write this byte array to our temporary file
    tempFile.Write(fileBytes)
    // return that we have successfully uploaded our file!
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Successfully Uploaded File\n")
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", uploadFile)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    setupRoutes()
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is an optimal solution. Reading the entire file into memory will be a bad choice, knowing that the file might be as huge as it gets.

It's safer to simply copy the files using the `io` package.